# Disable Warnings on CISCO WLC During Automated Configuration

Tags: cisco

I am creating a script to automate the configuration of a CISCO WLC and would like to know if there is a way to disable the warnings prior to the script running and then re-enable at the end.  This would eliminate having to answer the warning question.

For example if you send "auth-list ap-policy lsc enable" the return from the WLC is "Warning! Setting LSC mode does not apply to Mesh APs.Apply(y/n)?"  I would like to turn off the warnings and just have the Controller except the command and move on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use expect to deal with this if you're having the script push the config out. Since you know the question is coming, it's easy.

```
expect -re "(y/n)?\r"
send "y\r"
```

ALternatively, you can just autor the config as a flat file and

```
'transfer download datatype config'
```